# Undo doctrine:generate:entity creations?

Tags: php, symfony, version-control, doctrine

I am working with Symfony and Doctrine for the first time. I am curious: Is there a simple way to reverse a set of changes generated via a single running of the `doctrine:generate:entity` command?

I don't have any specific reason (yet) for asking this. I just imagine that it could potentially be helpful for me at some time in the near future, especially since my current version control only covers changes to the filesystem, omitting modifications to my sandbox's database contents -- <s>which is relevant here</s>.

In other words, some real equivalent for my imagined command `doctrine:generate:rollback` would be ideal. I'm assuming there's probably a way to do this type of thing.

Edit: TIL that the `doctrine:generate:entity` doesn't actually do anything to the database on its own. In many workflows, the `doctrine:schema:update` command does that after entities have been generated.

Comment: Side note, when you do go through the entire process of generating entities from the database https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html , Doctrine will create "<entity>.php~" files as the backup, if the entities already exist in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no `Symfony` or `Doctrine` command to do a rollback, but what `doctrine:generate:entity` really does is generating new php file with entity definition. So an actual rollback for `doctrine:generate:entity` is:

```
rm /path/to/your/entity.php
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized that no changes were made to the database by that entity generation command. (As I said, I'm coming at this completely fresh.) That's very good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No, there is no 'rollback' command, which removing all changes.

Do not forget that all changes in file system you can rollback via GIT (or other VCS).